# Does <!DOCUMENT html> trigger "use strict" in JS scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

My primitive (practice) JS script stops working when I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag at the top of the html file.
The html file itself is very simple and it is HTML5 compliant.
My script uses methods unsupported by JS strict mode though - methods like eval().
My question is - does the html5  tag enforce strict mode on my JS scripts? If no, what does the tag change functionally-wise?

My html body looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body><div>
    <p>...</p>
    <input id="bokDocelowy" class="input" value="50" />
    <p>...</p>
    <input id="czas" class="input" value="2000" />
    <button id="butt">Go!</button>
    <div id="kwadrat"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The script itself is pretty messy and I don't want to burn your brains sharing it with you. ;)

Thanks for any hints guys!

Cheers,
greg

Comment: JS strict mode is not triggered by the HTML5 doctype. Any error messages of your script?

Comment: No, there is no error message whatsoever. The script runs, but doesn't update the css properties correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Doctype switching has no relation to JavaScript's strict mode. Its *primary* effect is to stop emulation of CSS bugs that appeared in old browsers. When it breaks JS, it is *usually* because the JS is generating CSS dynamically and incorrectly (like setting number values on CSS properties that require lengths).

Comment: There are a few quirks that effect JS, however. `getElementsByClassName` becomes case-insensitive, most notably.

Comment: Quentin, thanks for the hint - the script is updating a css 'width' property of a div in a loop. It was tricky to do so, as css properties are strings (like "150px"), so I had to slice the current property (remove 'px'), add it to the value I wanted to update it and put both of those values to eval() method in order to actually add two strings. At the end I add + "px" in order to convert eveything back to a string and assign it to ...style.width property. Everything works fine without the <!DOCTYPE html> tag... Not working with it in place though...

Comment: Quentin! I have considered your answer a little bit more and it appeared that you were right! I actually forgot to add the + "px" statement at the end of my assignement. Thanks a lot mate! I wish I could vote you up, but I have too little rep ;)